# datetime2 overflow error

Tags: sql, datetime2

I'm trying to add 13 years to a birthdate that's stored as datetime2 using the following syntax and (dateadd(yy,13,isNull(cast(p.birthDTS as datetime),cast('1/1/1950' as datetime)))>=@svcStart)

and I get the *Adding a value to a 'datetime' column caused an overflow.*

I searched for the max(p.birthDTS) and it returned 1988-10-17 00:00:00.0000000

I got the for @svcStart as 2015-04-08 13:10:49.193

I'm a bit flummoxed.  Any help?

jb

Comment: What's the *`MIN`* value of `birthDTS`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with values that are `DATETIME2` you may want to try casting your values to `DATETIME2` as opposed to `DATETIME` :

```
DATEADD(yy,13,ISNULL(CAST(p.birthDTS AS DATETIME2),CAST('1/1/1950' AS DATETIME2)))
```

Assuming you don't have any invalid data or a similar issue and the example data that you provided is correct (i.e. the largest is `1988-10-17`), which seems correct as [seen here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/6983) :

[image]

I'd make sure that you double check all of your data types to ensure they are defined as expected and consider querying through your data again to check any edge-cases (e.g. largest and smallest values, possible nulls, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You might face this error if the value in your records in the datefield is not a valid date or if u add some months or date to this value and the output of that will exceed the date range.

Comment: You were right.  The max birthdate in the table is obviously an error at 9999-01-01 00:00:00.0000000, but I'm going to need to check for it to exclude the error.  Thanks so much for your comment.

Comment: @user1795131 So when you said, "I searched for the max(p.birthDTS) and it returned 1988-10-17 00:00:00.0000000"..?